# when run `win` command in acme the prompt is showing odd symbols

Tags: editor, acme, plan-9

I'm starting the `acme` from a `bash` shell with minimum settings, and my system default shell is `zsh`.

When I run `win` in `acme` I got the following prompt, I believe it's due to some color-related setting for shell, but I can't figure out where to reset it to make sure the prompt shows the correct colors for `win`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the wired stuff is coming from the `color` option of `zsh`.

After switching to the basic `zsh` setting, without syntax highlight, the above odd symbols disappear.